# More highly structured exports not working

Tags: org-export

Following this org export tutorial --
`https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html` --
I evaluated -- in an `emacs -q` instance --

```
(require 'ox-latex)
(unless (boundp 'org-latex-classes)
  (setq org-latex-classes nil))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("article"
               "\\documentclass{article}"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

and exported

```
* one
** two
*** three
**** four
```

but the last heading was still exported into an enumerate environment instead of into a paragraph.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org mode exports structured headlines only up to a depth of `org-export-headline-levels`. Try `C-h v` on this variable to read more. Headlines deeper than this level, which is **3** by default, are exported as lists - `\{enumerate}` in LaTeX.

To get the structure you want you can either set the variable to 4 or more manually or using Customize. It can also be set on a per-file basis, using `#+OPTIONS`

```
#+OPTIONS: H:4
* one
** two
*** three
**** four
```

Comment: Odd that the tutorial said nothing about that, when it showed a 5 level customization.

Comment: Yes - although the tutorial says it's for Org Mode < v8.0. It's possible that this feature was modified or possibly the default value changed somewhere in the past few years.